# Usefulness of reciprocal system of vectors

Tags: vectors

> If $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are 3 non-zero, non-collinear, non-coplanar vectors then the reciprocal system of vectors  for $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are
>   $$
> \vec{a}'=\frac{\vec{b}\times\vec{c}}{[\vec{a} \;\vec{b}\;\vec{c}]}\;;\vec{b}'=\frac{\vec{c}\times\vec{a}}{[\vec{a} \;\vec{b}\;\vec{c}]}\;;\vec{c}'=\frac{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}{[\vec{a} \;\vec{b}\;\vec{c}]}
> $$

Mathematically reciprocal vectors are vectors in the direction perpendicular to the remaining two vectors. And $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}'=\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}'=\vec{c}\cdot\vec{c}'=1$, so it seems like these are defined to introduce some kind of reciprocal to a vector since the division of vectors are undefined.

Could someone give more insight into why the concept of reciprocal vectors are introduced and what exactly is the purpose of such a concept ?

Is there a simple and basic physical or mathematical problem where these are made use of ?

Comment: @ThomasShelby this is the common example I have come across but its little higher standard for me to fully understand. So I was wondering is there any basic and simple application to this concept ?

Comment: The most important uses of reciprocal vectors is they allow you to reconstruct a vector from its dot products. i.e. $$p = (p\cdot a)a' + (p \cdot b)b' + (p\cdot c)c'$$

Comment: @achillehui thanx. I think that makes some sense. So given three non-collinear, non-zero, non-coplanar vectors, we can generate any vector from its dot product with the 3 vectors?

Comment: @ss1729 yes, if you know the dot product of a vector with 3 linear independent vectors, you can reconstruct that vector. What you need is multiply by the dot product with corr.reciprocal vector and sum them (i.e. the formula in previous comment).